# Parsing a C file in python for analyses

Tags: python, list, parsing, dictionary

From a C file I'd like to parse *switch* parts to be able to identify 2 things :

**a switch with only 2 cases :**

```
switch(Data)
  {
    case 0: value = 10 ; break;
    case 1 : value = 20 ;break;    
    default:
      somevar = false;
      value = 0 ;
       ----
      break;
  }
```

==> for instance would print "section with 2 case"

**a switch with many (unlimited) cases :**

```
switch(Data)
  {
    case Constant1 : value = 10 ; break;
    case constant2 : value = 20 ;break;    
    case constant3 : value = 30 ;break;    
    case constant4 : value = 40 ;break;    
    default:
      somevar = false;
      value = 0 ;
       ----
      break;
  }
```

==> would print "section with case : Constant1, Constant2, Constant3, Constant4"

To do that, I've done the following :

```
original_file = open(original_file,"r")
    for line in original_file:
        line_nb +=1
        regex_case = re.compile('.*case.*:')
        found_case = regex_case.search(line)
        if found_case :
            cases_dict[line_nb]=found_case.group()    # rely on line nb is somewhat not reliable as the c file may have break on an additional line
    bool_or_enum(cases_dict)
```

what would need the *bool_or_enum* to test all the required results:

```
def bool_or_enum(in_dict={}):
    sorted_dict = sorted(in_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    for index, item in enumerate(sorted_dict):
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you use a proper parser rather than try to write regular expressions - https://github.com/eliben/pycparser looks just what you need. For example, what happens if the C code contains a string literal with the word "case:" in it?

Comment: Isn't the test you're looking for just the length of `sorted_dict`? (Also: no need to `re.compile` your regex inside the loop. Also: what if a single source file contains *two* `switches`? Also: don't use regexes to parse C.)

Comment: @Tom Dalton : indeed a dedicated C parser is best but I have to admit that I couldn't make the pycparser runing on windows to identify cases.

Comment: thanks @Jongware for the remarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments I've searching and found that 2 solutions can be provided :

- by using **pycparser**

  *pros*: is a python package, free and opensource

  *cons* : not really easy to start with, need addtional tools to preprocess files (gcc, llvm, etc) .
- by using an **external tool** : understand from [scitools](https://scitools.com/)
  This tool is usable with its GUI to build a complete project to parse so you can have call graph, metrics, code checking, etc. . For this question I've been using the API which is available as [docs](https://scitools.com/sup/api-2/) and [examples](https://scitools.com/support/api-3lexers-and-lexemes/)

  *pros*:

  - the parsing is totally done by the tool from the GUI
  - I have many source files, re-parsing from a complete directory is a "push-button" solution

  *cons* :

  - not free
  - not open sourced

I usually prefer open source project but in that case Understand is the unique solution. By the way the license is not so expensive and over all : I've chosen this because I could parse some files that couldn't be compiled because their dependencies (libs and header files) couldn't be available.

Here is the code I've used :

```
import understand

understand_file="C:\\Users\\dlewin\\myproject.udb"
#Create a list with all the cases from the file
def find_cases(file):
    returnList =  []
    for lexeme in file.lexer(False,8,False,True):         
      if ( lexeme.text() == "case" ) :
        returnList.append(lexeme.line_end())    #line nb
        returnList.append(lexeme.text())        #found a case
    return returnList

def find_identifiers(file):
  returnList =  []

  # Open the file lexer with macros expanded and  inactive code removed
  for lexeme in file.lexer(False,8,False,True):
    if(lexeme.token() == "Identifier"):
        returnList.append(lexeme.line_end())    #line nb
        returnList.append(lexeme.text())        #identifier found
  return returnList

db = understand.open(understand_file )                                      # Open Database
file = db.lookup("mysourcefile.cpp","file")[0]
print (file.longname())
liste_idents = find_identifiers(file)                                       
liste_cases = find_cases(file)
```

Comment: Both `find_*()` functions look _very_ similar which should be refactored IMHO. It also looks like the result lists contain elements where items at odd indexes have a different meaning than items at even indexes. Usually lists contain items with the same meaning as anything else complicated further processing. I'd simply store tuples in that lists.

Comment: you are right, the 2 functions would need refactoring.  thanks for the remark about tuples. I need some improvement for my python